# Why can't I tame my ocelot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a cat house for my zoo on Minecraft. I have some untamed ocelots and I also want a few tamed ocelots. Fish only puts them in breeding mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order for an ocelot to become tamed, you must feed it while it is walking toward you. Don't force the cat. ***Stay still***, don't make sudden movements while it's walking towards you, or else it'll get scared and run off.

Answer (score 8):

From the "[Ocelot](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocelot)" page on the wiki:

> #### Taming
>
> An ocelot can be tamed by attracting it to the player with an uncooked fish of any kind, then fed the fish, which can turn it into one of three breeds of Cat that will then follow the player. Taming an ocelot is likely to take more than one fish.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Breeding
>
> When **tamed** cats are fed raw fish, they will immediately enter "breed-mode"

Ocelots will only enter breeding mode if they have been tamed. This means you have already tamed your cats!

By looking at your cat you can see if they have been tamed. If they look like this they have not been tamed:

[image]

When you tame a cat, they will turn into one of three breeds of cat, and look like this:

[image]

You can also check if they have been tamed by right clicking on your cat, they will sit down if they have been tamed.

If you want to know how to tame an Ocelot I recommend you read [this article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocelot#Taming).  It explains it really well and I guarantee it will help you.

Comment: That made no sense to me but ok..

Comment: No help whatsover

Comment: I have edited my answer to hopefully make it easier to understand.

Comment: Yes but HOW do you tame it?

Comment: Right-click with raw fish in your hand on an approaching ocelot until it emits hearts.